# Vaadin 24 : Could not navigate to '' Issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have added vaadin security to my vaadin project. After successfull login It shows this error message in the screen.

I added spring security to the pom.xml. Created a custome authentication provider. Authentication part is working correctly.

vaadin version : 24.1.6

This is the package structure

[image]

```
public class MainLayout extends AppLayout {

    public MainLayout() {
        createHeader();
//      createDrawer();
    }

    private void createHeader(){
        H1 logo = new H1("AuthX Server");
        logo.getStyle().set("font-weight","bold").set("color","#150050");
        logo.addClassNames(
                LumoUtility.FontSize.LARGE,  // Instead of styling text with raw CSS, use Lumo Utility Classes shipped with the default theme
                LumoUtility.Margin.MEDIUM
        );
        
        var header = new HorizontalLayout(logo);

        header.setDefaultVerticalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
        header.setWidth("100%");
        header.addClassNames("py-0", "px-m");
        header.setHeight("5%");
        header.getStyle().set("background","#9fcbfc");
        addToNavbar(header);
    }

    private void createDrawer() {
        addToDrawer(new VerticalLayout(
                new RouterLink("List", ListView.class)
        ));
        setDrawerOpened(false);
    }


}
```

```
@Route("login")
@PageTitle("Login | AuthX Server")
@AnonymousAllowed
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    private final LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();

    public LoginView() {
        addClassName("login-view");
        setSizeFull();
        setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);

        loginForm.setAction("login");
        add(new H1("AuthX Server"), loginForm);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {
        // inform the user about and authentication error
        if (beforeEnterEvent.getLocation()
                .getQueryParameters()
                .getParameters()
                .containsKey("error")) {
            loginForm.setError(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Part of the ListView class:

```
@PermitAll
@PageTitle("Users | AuthX Server")
@Route(value = "", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class ListView extends VerticalLayout {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ListView.class);
    VAuthService vAuthService;
    private Grid<JSONProfile> grid = new Grid<>(JSONProfile.class, false);
    private AddUserForm addUserForm;
    private AddUserDialogBox addUserDialogBox;
    private TextField filterText = new TextField();

    @Autowired
    JSONHelper jsonHelper;

    private AddUserFormProperties addUserFormProperties;

    public ListView(VAuthService vAuthService, AddUserFormProperties servicesProperties) throws KeyException {
        this.vAuthService = vAuthService;
        this.addUserFormProperties = servicesProperties;
        addClassName("list-view");
        setSizeFull();

        configureAddUserForm();
        configureAddUserDialogBox();

        configureGrid();

        add(getToolbar(), grid);
        updateList();
        closeEditor();
    }

    private void configureAddUserDialogBox() {
        addUserDialogBox = new AddUserDialogBox(addUserForm);
        addUserDialogBox.addClickListener(click -> addUser());
    }
```

Do you have any idea? I am new to the vaadin development

Comment: Are you using url mapping in your configuration?

Comment: Yes, I am using some urls in configuration